# Is there a way to edit the body in a React app after importing Reactstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've successfully edited the body (e.g. changing background-color) in React through App.css when it's imported into App.js for a standard React app.

However, on this project, I decided to incorporate Reactstrap and, while I'm able to edit certain tags in App.css, the body isn't one of them. Did I overlook something and/or is there a vanilla solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean you can't edit `body` in `App.css`? like the style doesn't apply for some reason?

Comment: This may not be an all-encompassing solution, but I managed to at least solve this styling issue. Turns out it was an issue in import order in `index.js`, where I imported `bootstrap.min.css` before `App.js`. I changed the order and things are working as intended.